# awk to extract tags between two files

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below which executes as is and results in the current output, I am trying to add a condition that will extract the text or
value after the tags `AF=`,`FR=`, `HRUN=`,`LEN=`,`TYPE=` for the lines in each line of `file1` compared to `file2`. As is the lines between
the two files are either a `Match`, `Missing in file 1`, or `Missing in file2`,but I can not add the conditions to extract  up to the `;` (semi-colon).
There may not always be text after the tags, but they always ends with a `;`. The decimal in `$6` is also 3 signifigant figures to make it easier to read. It seems
close but there are a couple things I am not quite sure how to do.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
chr1    43814978    COSM27286    G    A    86.92679999999999    PASS    
AF=0;AO=1;DP=5535;FAO=0;FR=.,REALIGNEDx0.008;HRUN=1;LEN=1;TYPE=snp;VARB=0;HS; 
chr1    43814981    COSM27287    G    A    86.83350000000002    PASS    
AF=0;AO=2;DP=5556;FAO=0;FR=.;HRUN=1;LEN=1;TYPE=snp;VARB=0;HS;
chr1    43815008    COSM29008;COSM43212    TGG    AAA,AAG    70.3099    PASS        
AF=0,0;AO=0,0;DP=5528;FAO=0,0;FR=.,.,;HRUN=1,1;LEN=3,2,;TYPE=mnp,mnp;VARB=0,0;HS;
```

**file2**

```
chr1    43814979    COSM27286    G    A    86.92679999999999    PASS    
AF=0;AO=1;DP=5535;FAO=0;FR=.,REALIGNEDx0.008;HRUN=1;LEN=1;TYPE=snp;VARB=0;HS; 
chr1    43814981    COSM27287    G    A    86.83350000000002    PASS    
AF=0;AO=2;DP=5556;FAO=0;FR=.;HRUN=1;LEN=1;TYPE=snp;VARB=0;HS;
chr1    43815008    COSM29008;COSM43212    TGG    AAA,AAG    70.3099    PASS        
AF=0,0;AO=0,0;DP=5528;FAO=0,0;FR=.,.,;HRUN=1,1;LEN=3,2,;TYPE=mnp,mnp;VARB=0,0;HS;
```

**desired output**

```
Match:
chr1    43814981    COSM27287    G    A    86.8    PASS    
AF=0;FR=.;HRUN=1;LEN=1;TYPE=snp
chr1    43815008    COSM29008;COSM43212    TGG    AAA,AAG    70.3099    PASS        
AF=0,0;FR=.,.,;HRUN=1,1;LEN=3,2,;TYPE=mnp,mnp
Missing in file1:
chr1    43814979    COSM27286    G    A    86.9    PASS    
AF=0;FR=.,REALIGNEDx0.008;HRUN=1;LEN=1;TYPE=snp
Missing in file2:
chr1    43814978    COSM27286    G    A    86.9    PASS    
AF=0;FR=.,REALIGNEDx0.008;HRUN=1;LEN=1;TYPE=snp
```

**awk**

```
awk 'FNR==1 { next }
 FNR == NR { file1[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7] = $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " "$7 }
 FNR != NR { file2[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7] = $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " "$7 }
 END { print "Match:"; for (k in file1) if (k in file2) print file1[k] # Or file2[k]
       print "Missing in file1:"; for (k in file2) if (!(k in file1)) print file2[k]
       print "Missing in file2:"; for (k in file1) if (!(k in file2)) print file1[k]
 }' file1 file2 > output
```

**Current output**

```
Match:
chr1 43814981 COSM27287 G A 86.83350000000002 PASS
chr1 43815008 COSM29008;COSM43212 TGG AAA,AAG 70.3099 PASS
Missing in File1:
chr1 43814979 COSM27286 G A 86.92679999999999 PASS
Missing in File2:
chr1 43814978 COSM27286 G A 86.92679999999999 PASS
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logic for 2nd line in match which should come as (COSM29008;COSM43212;COSM19193;COSM27289;COSM28487) is coming only to (COSM29008;COSM43212)?

Comment: You seem to have asked sufficient questions in `awk` to atleast make a decent effort towards solving the problem. But you keep asking for free code?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my end you are correct in your code. Sorry and Thank you :).

Comment: I have made numerous posts and have learned a great deal from them but not as much as is needed. This is a bit outside of the realm of science, my expertise, but I appreciate the help and don't mean to upset or frustrate.  I do make, seeming minor or fundamental mistakes, but thats part of learning. Thank you :).

Comment: You can't see in your code that `file1[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7] = $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " "$7 }` could be written as just `file1[$0]=$0` (but why would you even write that?). You asked a question and accepted the first answer you got within 20 mins of asking it (think about that - what are the odds of the very first answer you get being the best possible one?) even though it doesn't produce the output you say you wanted and has other obvious issues. Maybe there's something you could do differently to learn from the questions you're asking?

Comment: Thank you for your help and yes I need to approach this differently and maybe that will help. So then would a better approach be  `file1[$0]=$0` to `file2[$0]=$0`, then looking for the tags and utilizing `printf` for the decimal?  Thank you :).

Comment: As I read, ask questions, and even answer so I learn more, but as @Ed Morton suggests I need a better approach and always read and make an attempt, but think more is needed. Thank you :)

Comment: Once you've accepted an answer YMMV with posting additional questions as comments unless they're under that answer and directed to the person whose answer you accepted. In this case since the accepted answer doesn't produce the output you said you wanted, we don't know **what** it is you're really trying to do and so it becomes impossible to give you advice, sorry. I'm not even really sure if your input file is really in pairs of lines or if you put line breaks in by mistake after every odd numbered line. You might want to ask a new, clearer question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
             a[$1,$2,$7]=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7;
             next
            }
     (($1,$2,$7) in a){
             val_match=val_match?val_match ORS a[$1,$2,$7]:a[$1,$2,$7];
             delete a[$1,$2,$7];
             next
                      }
{
    val_mismatch_in_file1=val_mismatch_in_file1?val_mismatch_in_file1 ORS $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7:$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7;
}
END{
    for(i in a){
        val_missing_in_file2=val_missing_in_file2?a[i]:a[i]};
        print "Match:" RS val_match RS "Missing in File1:" RS val_mismatch_in_file1 RS "Missing in File2:" RS val_missing_in_file2
   }
    '  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Match:
chr1 43814981 COSM27287 G A 86.83350000000002 PASS
chr1 43815008 COSM29008;COSM43212;COSM19193;COSM27289;COSM28487 TGG AAA,AAG,AGG,CGG,GCG 70.3099 PASS
Missing in File1:
chr1 43814979 COSM27286 G A 86.92679999999999 PASS
Missing in File2:
chr1 43814978 COSM27286 G A 86.92679999999999 PASS
```